# Kronecker Power of sparse matrices problem

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create a sparse matrix using scipy package.
Why the following code does not work? I try it also in loops.

```
import numpy

from scipy import sparse

from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

def SparseMatrixPower(A,p):
    if p == 1: 
        return(A)
    elif Mod(p,2):
        return(SparseMatrixPower(A,SparseMatrixProduct(A,A)), (p - 1) / 2)  
    else:
        return(SparseMatrixPower(SparseMatrixProduct(A,A), p / 2))

def SparseMatrixProduct(A,B):
        return(sparse.kron(A,B)+sparse.kronsum(A,B))

A=sparse.coo_matrix([[0,1,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,3]])
B=sparse.coo_matrix([[0,1,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,3]])
SparseMatrixProduct(A,B)
SparseMatrixPower(A,3)
```

Error message is below which I am getting:

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     19 B=sparse.coo_matrix([[Integer(0),Integer(1),Integer(2)],[Integer(1),Integer(1),Integer(2)],[Integer(2),Integer(2),Integer(3)]])
     20 SparseMatrixProduct(A,B)
---> 21 SparseMatrixPower(A,Integer(11))

```
<ipython-input-7-9b98e47610f5> in SparseMatrixPower(A, p)
      9         return(A)
     10     elif Mod(p,Integer(2)):
---> 11         return(SparseMatrixPower(A,SparseMatrixProduct(A,A)), (p - Integer(1)) / Integer(2))
     12     else:
     13         return(SparseMatrixPower(SparseMatrixProduct(A,A), p / Integer(2)))

<ipython-input-7-9b98e47610f5> in SparseMatrixPower(A, p)
      6 
      7 def SparseMatrixPower(A,p):
----> 8     if p == Integer(1):
      9         return(A)
     10     elif Mod(p,Integer(2)):

/home/calc/SageMath/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __bool__(self)
    286             return self.nnz != 0
    287         else:
--> 288             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
    289                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
    290     __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your code not working? Please describe the error.

Comment: What is `Mod` supposed to be?

Comment: And `SparseMatrixPower(A,A)` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, this is typo. I corrected. The same with the matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code `SparseMatrixPower(A, SparseMatrixProduct(A, A))` is not in the intention of the function `SparseMatrixPower`, which wants as second argument an integer. The error message points to this, and it seems that the code was started from the sagemath ipython interpreter.

Let us better try a version of the above code, which better suits `pep8` guidelines:

```
import numpy

from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

def SparseMatrixProduct(A, B):
    return sparse.kron(A, B) + sparse.kronsum(A, B)

def SparseMatrixPower(A, p):
    if p == 1: 
        return(A)
    phalf = int(p/2)    # p/2 truncated if not int 
    rest = p - 2*phalf
    AA = SparseMatrixProduct(A, A)
    B = SparseMatrixPower(AA, phalf)
    if not rest:
        return B
    return SparseMatrixProduct(A, B)

A = sparse.coo_matrix([[0,1,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,3]])
B = sparse.coo_matrix([[0,1,2],[1,1,2],[2,2,3]])

AB = SparseMatrixProduct(A, B)
A3 = SparseMatrixPower(A,3)
```

The above works for me.
Printing the objects `AB` and `A3` above is not really supported by the format of this site, i will also use the ipython interpreter to show `AB` and the shape and some first elements of `A3`.

Well, `AB` "is":

```
sage: AB
<9x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 81 stored elements (blocksize = 3x3) in Block Sparse Row format>
sage: AB.todense()
matrix([[ 0,  1,  2,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  4],
        [ 1,  1,  2,  1,  2,  2,  2,  4,  4],
        [ 2,  2,  3,  2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  8],
        [ 1,  1,  2,  1,  2,  4,  2,  2,  4],
        [ 1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  4,  2,  4,  4],
        [ 2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  7,  4,  4,  8],
        [ 2,  2,  4,  2,  2,  4,  3,  4,  8],
        [ 2,  4,  4,  2,  4,  4,  4,  7,  8],
        [ 4,  4,  8,  4,  4,  8,  8,  8, 15]])
```

and the 3³ x 3³ matrix `A3` is shown in part, first few lines and columns:

```
sage: A3.shape
(27, 27)
sage: A3.todense()[0:15, 0:15]
matrix([[ 0,  1,  2,  1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  2],
        [ 1,  1,  2,  0,  1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  1,  2,  2,  1,  3,  2],
        [ 2,  2,  3,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  2,  2,  2,  4,  2,  2,  5],
        [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  0,  0,  2,  1,  2,  3,  2,  4],
        [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  2,  2,  0,  2,  0,  1,  3,  2,  2,  5,  4],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  2,  2,  4,  0,  0,  2,  2,  2,  5,  4,  4,  9],
        [ 2,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  1,  2,  4,  2,  4,  4,  2,  4],
        [ 0,  2,  0,  0,  2,  0,  1,  4,  2,  2,  6,  4,  2,  6,  4],
        [ 0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  2,  2,  2,  6,  4,  4, 10,  4,  4, 10],
        [ 1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  2,  4,  2,  4,  1,  2,  4,  3,  1,  2],
        [ 1,  2,  2,  1,  3,  2,  2,  6,  4,  2,  3,  4,  1,  4,  2],
        [ 2,  2,  4,  2,  2,  5,  4,  4, 10,  4,  4,  7,  2,  2,  6],
        [ 2,  1,  2,  3,  2,  4,  4,  2,  4,  3,  1,  2,  4,  3,  6],
        [ 1,  3,  2,  2,  5,  4,  2,  6,  4,  1,  4,  2,  3,  7,  6],
        [ 2,  2,  5,  4,  4,  9,  4,  4, 10,  2,  2,  6,  6,  6, 13]])
sage:
```